# Live streaming of images in a LAN

Tags: image, encoding, video-streaming, live, video-encoding

I have a proprietary library that generates JPEG images at 10-20Hz. I'd like to stream the images as a video stream over the network, so that a remote client (VLC for example) will be able to view it.

The clients are all in a LAN and there are no restrictions on the streaming protocol and the video format. The environment is Windows 7/XP and the library DLL exports a C-only API.

Is there a recommended library that allows streaming image frames, injected in real-time? the streaming libraries I know (VLC and Live555) do not allow this AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M-JPEG defines streaming over HTTP by sending individual images. This protocol is understood by VLC.

From Wikipedia:

> **M-JPEG over HTTP**
>
> HTTP streaming
> separates each image into individual
> HTTP replies on a specified marker.
> RTP streaming creates packets of a
> sequence of JPEG images that can be
> received by clients such as QuickTime
> or VLC. The server software mentioned
> above streams the sequence of JPEGs
> over HTTP. A special mime-type content
> type
> `multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=`
> informs the browser to expect several
> parts as answer separated by a special
> boundary. This boundary is defined
> within the MIME-type. For M-JPEG
> streams the JPEG data is sent to the
> client with a correct HTTP-header. The
> TCP connection is not closed as long
> as the client wants to receive new
> frames and the server wants to provide
> new frames. Two basic implementations
> of such a server are test-server
> "cambozola" and webcam server
> "MJPG-Streamer".
>
> **Client software**
>
> Browsers such as Safari, Google Chrome
> and Opera stream M-JPEG natively.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG#M-JPEG_over_HTTP

Comment: Thanks. Any recommendations for a Windows library to stream M-JPEG? MJPG-Streamer seems to run only on Linux, and cambozola test server is indeed a test application (which could be extended, of course).

Comment: Not really, but protocol seems easy enough to implement with anything.